# Express - Accessing the values in post request to use in my get request

Tags: node.js, express

Reworded due to lack of clarity.

I have my post request method

```
  app.post("/api/animals", (req, res, next) => {
    const search = new Search({
      gps: req.body.gps

    });
   var search1 = JSON.stringify(req.body.gps);
  console.log(search1);
    console.log(search);
    search.save();

    res.status(201).json({
      message: 'Search Successful'


    });
  });
```

and my get request method

```
app.get('/api/animals',(req, res, next) => {

  const search = new Search({
    gps: req.body.gps

  });
 var search1 = JSON.stringify(req.query.gps);
 console.log(search1)
  Animal.find({})

  .then(documents => {
  res.status(200).json({
    message: 'Complete Sucess',
    animals: documents
  });
});

  });
```

I want to use the data I am posting `search` or `search1` in my `Animal.find()` method in my get request. How can I make this data available to use in app.get or have it so when data is posted it searches automatically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to re-use the `Animal.find(` code in two places. Is that correct?

Something like this?

```js
function findAnimals(criteria) {
  return Animal.find(criteria);
}
```

```js
app.post("/api/animals", (req, res, next) => {
  // ...
  findAnimals(search).then(documents => {
  res.status(200).json({
    message: 'Complete Sucess',
    animals: documents
  });
});
```

```js
app.get('/api/animals',(req, res, next) => {
  // ...
  findAnimals(search).then(documents => {
  res.status(200).json({
    message: 'Complete Sucess',
    animals: documents
  });
});
```

Comment: Not so much that but I want to use the parsed data from the search const in the get request. But due to the scope its not available

Comment: Those would be two separate requests.